# Claims authentication event ID 8306 error, cannot start USPS service after expired password change

Tags: user-profile-service

About 2 days ago the password expired for the farm account due to someone not using the function to never expire passwords. Anyways, after this I went thru CA and changed the password but now I can't get the User Profile Sync Service to work. If I look in the Event Viewer I keep on getting an error in SharePoint Foundation with Event ID 8306 and the message is `The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was ''.`. Anyone who can point me in the right direction on where to look? 
I also have the issue of the FIM not starting but I'm guessing this is all related to eachother.

I can also add that the User Profile Synchronization Service is stuck on "Starting" and that I've recreated the User Profile Service Application several times now.

Comment: I "solved" this by backing up the site collection and then reinstalling without reinstalling Sharepoint (followed Todd Klindts guide on [his blog](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=179)  ).

Comment: You should answer the question with you findings and then close it. It will help people having the same problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "solved" this by backing up the site collection and then reinstalling without reinstalling Sharepoint (followed Todd Klindts guide [on his blog](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=179) ).

(posting "answer" as suggested by Rodrigo Molinas)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

Upon receiving this error message, the Authentication settings for the SharePoint Web Services (this is the site responsible for issuing the security tokens).

Under IIS 7 > Sites > SharePoint Web Services > Authentication > Windows Authentication (enabled) > Advanced Settings > Check Enable Kernal-mode authentication.

The "Enable Kernal-mode authentication" was unchecked, upon checking this setting and completing an IISRESET (from PowerShell) the Security Token issue was resolved and the alert no longer shows in Central Administration.

Reference: http://dokuforest.com/start/?p=72